# Prometheus Absent Metric on Labels

Tags: prometheus, jmx, dropwizard

I have an application that consumes messages from a kafka topic. The liveliness of the consuming loop is check by a Yammer guage called `llcPartitionConsuming` which is set to 1 whenever the consumption happens, and to 0 when the messages are being processed.

The problem I am facing is that when the consuming loop dies for some reason, this metric is not reported at all and any alerts I have on this metric are not evaluated. To detect the absence of this metric, I am using:

`absent(llcPartitionConsuming) == 1` in my alert rule defn, but this is triggered only when all the consuming loop dies on ALL servers (that is, when Prometheus does not find a time series for this metric AT ALL). However, I want an alert even when the consuming loop dies on a single server (this metric has `server` and `partition` as labels). How can I do that?

Comment: Can you clarify, described metrics are a part of some bigger batch of metrics, and you can't use `up` for this reason? Or something else?

Comment: Also, is there some metric that has exactly the same labels as `llcPartitionConsuming`, so that you can use it in expression like "if my_metric present, but llcPartitionConsuming is not - fire an alert"?

Comment: @markalex How can I use UP here? 

>if my_metric present, but llcPartitionConsuming is not

This will not allow me to trigger when llcPartitionConsuming is not present for just a subset of labels, will it?

Comment: If target and `llcPartitionConsuming` are in 1-to-1 relation, and your problem results in full stoppage of metrics exposure - you can simply use `up==0` to detect targets that are not scraped.

Comment: "This will not allow" - not, it will allow you exactly that. If it's present - we can do it simply (using `unless`). If it's not - a bit more complicated (`unless` and `offset`)